# Best option for wordpress mobile theme with mobile url

Tags: wordpress, mobile

I want to build a mobile site on wordpress.
What Im looking to do is detect if its being loaded on a mobile device and then switch themes based on this.

Usually I implement a redirect to a mobile m.mysite.com address when using different platforms, but is there a more efficient way of doing this on wordpress, where I can keep the address but have it load a different theme?

Im not keen on doing a responsive site as I want to completely restructure the layout.

Thank you

Comment: I know you're "not keen on RWD", but just make sure you're still providing the same content on all devices. Nothing more annoying than getting a "just for mobile" experience that lacks all of the features. http://gomakethings.com/content-parity-on-the-web/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This links will help you. Try it.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/any-mobile-theme-switcher/

http://wordpress.org/plugins/mobile-theme-switch/

http://wordpress.org/plugins/mobile-theme-switcher/

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the [Auto Mobile Theme Switcher plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/auto-mobile-theme-switcher/).

Answer (score 0):

Another option may be to add a WordPress Mobile Theme that creates a mobile optimized RESS (Responsive Server Sided) layer to your site - both WPTouch and JumpMobi offer this type of functionality you are looking for straight out of the box.

HTH